# Transaction + Select ... For Update... Skipping indexes

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, transactions, locking

I noticed something funny with my table's index column after running an experiment to answer a different question.

In my experiment, I had two conditions. In one, `autocommit=FALSE` and in another `autocommit=TRUE`. I had 2 sessions connected to the server and tried various combinations of session #1 starting transactions / selecting `FOR UPDATE` and session #2 attempting selects and inserts, etc under those conditions. Important note: all transactions started by session #1 were rolled back, not committed.

Reviewing my results, I noticed that when the first session was in a transaction AND had selected `FOR UPDATE`, the insert made by session 2 (after the first session finished its transaction of course) had its index advanced by 2. In all other inserts by session 2 the index only advanced by 1. That includes inserts forced to wait because session 1 had selected `FOR UDPATE` (this is possible when autocommit is off btw).

Without losing another hour or two to testing, I was hoping someone could explain how the index advanced by 2. My best guess is this: I assume that the index +1 was reserved for session #1, which was rolled back instead of committed and the index + 2 was reserved for session #2 because it’s request came in while index +1 was reserved. After session #1 rolled back, nothing was put at index + 1, and session #2 inserted at the index already reserved for it, index + 2.

Is that true? If it is, I am concerned that if many sessions request to update at the same time and then don’t commit, whole patches of the index may go unused… Can I prevent this? Can I remediate it if and when it happens?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: By `index`, do you mean `autonumber`?

Comment: I assume by 'index' you mean an auto-increment primary key. (Index is formally defined and does not always apply to the primary key.) But the real question is "why do you care?" auto-index gaps don't cause any harm, other than aesthetics.